# Are there any companies from India using Stack Overflow careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I am just curious to know if there are any companies from India using SO careers to locate candidates? If not, is it worth spending money on Stack Overflow Careers?

Do you have any plans to focus on the Indian market?

Comment: Come on now, we all know "India" is a fiction created by our bosses to threaten us with "outsourcing".  Oh, hold on, my boss just handed me an envelope, brb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to what markets SO is going to focus on; I don't think that they are focusing on any particular market, apart from the SO users. My understanding is that it is their hope and intention that StackOverflow users who are looking for colleagues will try using http://jobs.stackoverflow.com, and from their, use the CV search function.

As others have said, in markets other than the US, they are facing a little bit of the chicken and egg problem. In the US, which admittedly has a massive proportion of programmers, $10 for a year is nothing, and so a lot of people will get a paid CV "just in case" it helps. This leads to more interest from American companies, since there are more American programmers, and so a cycle is created, and they reach a certain critical mass.

The site as a whole needs to become much larger so that the "20%" of jobs and jobseekers outside of the US get their own critical masses.

If you can easily afford the registration fee, then I would suggest that you do it, since you never know... However if it is not so easy to come by the money, then I would suggest that you don't do it, since unless you are in the US, or can work in the US without a H1-B, then you are less likely to find it immediately useful.

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't see anything that is wrong with what I said? Or is it just because I have the temerity to suggest that he shouldn't spend hard to come by cash on something that won't help him?

Answer (score 5):

At the moment, the top countries searched are

> **Top Countries**
>
> United States, United Kingdom, Canada,
>   Mexico, Spain, Czech Republic,
>   Germany, Norway, Australia, Italy,
>   Portugal, Netherlands, South Africa,
>   Egypt, Switzerland

The top locations lay within these countries, with predominance in the US.

I am Swiss, and even though Switzerland is on the top countries list, out of 2407 searches as off now I have been hit 8 times only in searches, 7 times in the beta phase alone, and never been contacted.

This leads me to the impression, and I might be wrong, that the top countries list is the exhaustive list of all countries companies participate in and that there is little activity outside the top 5, with a clear max in US and UK.

I would conclude that investing money in other countries is only an option if you are willing and able to relocate to one of the top countries.

It would be great to show the search stats and distribution of companies searching to potential candidates, not only a top list, but numbers of companies, candidates and searches conducted per country and area.

Obviously it is a taking and giving, or better a chicken and egg problem. There have to be enough potential candidates to have companies starting to search and vice versa.

As for focusing on a market: I do not think that J&J will advertise apart from SO sites for Careers. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The best information I have shows:

#### Top Countries

- United States
- United Kingdom
- Canada
- Mexico
- Spain
- Czech Republic
- Germany
- Norway
- Australia
- Italy
- Portugal
- Netherlands
- South Africa
- Egypt
- Switzerland

Comment: yeah i also saw this list in careers, i just wanted to know these are the only countries featured in SO or these are just top 15 countries.... whats the full list??

Comment: For what it is worth, assuming some kind of logarithmic fall-off, that probably is the full list, since there are only 214 employers, and most of those are probably in the US, certainly if we base it off of <http://jobs.stackoverflow.com>.

Answer (score 1):

At present I think the job adverts on “[joil on softwere job site](http://jobs.joelonsoftware.com/)” is a good indication but over time more employers will use one half of the service without the other half.